# gatsbyImageData unexpectedly `undefined`

Tags: gatsby

I am using the `Gatsby-source-airtable` plugin, and after mapping the Attachment field to fileNode the GraphQL explorer gives the following tree as being available for querying:

```
query MyQuery {
  allAirtable {
    edges {
      node {
        data {
          Name
          Rind
          Country
          Image {
            localFiles {
              childImageSharp {
                gatsbyImageData
              }
            }
          }
        }
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is definitely data returning for that query: here is the RHS of the GraphQL explorer:

```
"data": {
    "allAirtable": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "data": {
              "Name": "Beaufort AOP",
              "Rind": null,
              "Country": "France",
              "Image": {
                "localFiles": [
                  {
                    "childImageSharp": {
                      "gatsbyImageData": {
                        "layout": "constrained",
                        "backgroundColor": "#281818",
                        "images": {
                          "fallback": {
                            "src": "/static/e280ca168be73e9fbe0c73688532c7eb/de105/24-beaufort-shutterstock_447054049.jpg",
                            "srcSet": "/static/e280ca168be73e9fbe0c73688532c7eb/7ac0a/24-beaufort-shutterstock_447054049.jpg 250w,\n/static/e280ca168be73e9fbe0c73688532c7eb/51a07/24-beaufort-shutterstock_447054049.jpg 500w,\n/static/e280ca168be73e9fbe0c73688532c7eb/de105/24-beaufort-shutterstock_447054049.jpg 1000w",
                            "sizes": "(min-width: 1000px) 1000px, 100vw"
                          },
                          "sources": [
                            {
                              "srcSet": "/static/e280ca168be73e9fbe0c73688532c7eb/6ef21/24-beaufort-shutterstock_447054049.webp 250w,\n/static/e280ca168be73e9fbe0c73688532c7eb/12849/24-beaufort-shutterstock_447054049.webp 500w,\n/static/e280ca168be73e9fbe0c73688532c7eb/85e35/24-beaufort-shutterstock_447054049.webp 1000w",
                              "type": "image/webp",
                              "sizes": "(min-width: 1000px) 1000px, 100vw"
                            }
                          ]
                        },
                        "width": 1000,
                        "height": 750
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "id": "5d915174-a69e-5e9a-81df-387d0c6271de"
          }
        },
```

I try to load the image with the following code in my index.js:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'
import { container, item, title } from './index.module.css'
import { GatsbyImage, getImage } from 'gatsby-plugin-image'

const CheesePage = ({ data }) => {
  return (
      <main className={container}>
      <h1 className={title}>Cheese</h1>
        {
          data.allAirtable.edges.map((edge, i) => (
            <article key={edge.node.id} className={item}>
              <h2>{edge.node.data.Name}</h2>
              <p>From: {edge.node.data.Country}</p>
              <GatsbyImage image={edge.node.data.Image.localFiles.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData} alt="Image"/>
            </article>
          ))
        }
      </main>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allAirtable {
      edges {
        node {
          data {
            Name
            Rind
            Country
            Image {
              localFiles {
                  childImageSharp {
                    id
                    gatsbyImageData(
                      width: 200
                      placeholder: BLURRED
                      formats: [AUTO, WEBP, AVIF]
                    )
                  }
                }
            }
          }
          id
        }
      }
    }
}
`

export default CheesePage
```

But I am given the error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'edge.node.data.Image.localFiles.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData')`

Why is `gatsbyImageData` resolving as `undefined`? All the other data are pulling in just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The array of nodes of your data is `node`, not `edges` that's why your loop is failing. Change your loop to:

```
  {
      data.allAirtable.edges.node.map((node, i) => (
        <article key={node.id} className={item}>
          <h2>{node.data.Name}</h2>
          <p>From: {node.data.Country}</p>
          {node.data.Image.localFiles && 
            <GatsbyImage image={node.data.Image.localFiles.childImageSharp.gatsbyImageData} alt="Image"/>
          }
        </article>
      ))
    }
```

In that way, your rendering won't break and you will be able to check what image is missing (`undefined`) and is causing your issue.

If you want to follow your approach, you should destructure `node` like:

```
data.allAirtable.edges.map({ node }) => (...)
```

Comment: I have used the code in your first example and I still get exactly the same error

Comment: The iterable variable is `node`, not `edges`.

Comment: Are you sure? Now the error is `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.allAirtable.edges.node.map')`

Comment: Is as easy as print (`console.log(data)`) your variables to check how is your data structured. If you haven't played with type definitions, you have an array of nodes